# How to replace retina MacBook Pro rubber feet?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

The rubber feet of my late 2013, 15" retina Macbook Pro are breaking and falling off. From what I’ve gathered, Apple doesn’t sell these feet and expects you to pay about $100 for a replacement of the bottom panel.

But I’ve found some feet online (last image) and was told I do not need to remove the bottom panel to replace them. I’m somewhat doubtful if this claim and want to make sure.

Is there a tutorial with video or step-by-step photos that replaces these (including documenting the removal of the old ones)?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the instructions in the Apple Support document, [MacBook Pro: Bottom case foot replacement DIY instructions](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202450).

There is absolutely no need to shell out money to replace the entire bottom panel. However, the article explicitly mentions that the DIY replacement kit is not available for MacBook Pro with Retina display computers. The procedure shared appears quite straightforward.

As apparent from the article, glue can be used to stick the feet to the bottom panel. On the other hand, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8VIHAae8N2Y) Youtube video gives a good demonstration of how to remove the bottom panel and place the bottom feet the recommended way.

I have had a similar situation with my Late 2013 15" retina MacBook Pro. I have used glue to paste the falling off feet to the back panel.